# How to return image if preg_match_all() null

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function:

```
function mom_get_first_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches[1][0];
    if (empty($first_img)) {

        return "images/logo.png";
    } else {
        return $first_img;
    }
}
```

This function is show the post if have images is show me in post in front page of my site, but if no images I need to show the logo of my site.

I try to get logo if no images but its show me:

```
<img title="title" alt="title" src="" style="opacity: 1;">
```

If there image its show me:

```
<img title="title" alt="title" src="images/111.jpg" style="opacity: 1;">
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: You should add some comments to the code. It's a little hard to figure out what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your regex. It does not capture the attribute if it is empty because it wants at least one character that is not a quote. You have to change it so that it takes 0 or more. If you change it to this it will capture it.

```
'/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]*)[\'"].*>/i'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mom_get_first_image()
{
    global $post;
    if(preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches))
        $first_img = $matches[1][0];
    else
        $first_img = "images/logo.png";
    return $first_img;
}
```